# How to bring the userform in the excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed an `UserForm` VBA module.

But i want that userform when opening the excel sheet itself? WheN I open [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) the `UserForm` should should show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the Excel Application but show a UserFrom you could use this in the `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To open when you open the workbook in the ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Userform1.Show
End Sub
```

Replace UserForm1 with the name of the Userform, if different.

To open when you enter a particular sheet in the sheet Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```